# Type hinting in pydev for several parameters

Tags: python, python-2.7, pydev, type-hinting

So I am in need of some type hinting in pydev and have found this : http://pydev.org/manual_adv_type_hints.html

```
class MyClass:

def method(self, a):
    ':type a: ClassA'
```

This works as a charm.

However if I have something like this:
    class MyClass:

```
def method(self, a, b):
    ':type a: ClassA'
```

How do I get type hints for both parameters?
I have tried all kinds of combinations of

```
':type a,b: ClassA, ClassB
```

or

```
':type a, ClassA'
':type b, ClassB'
```

or

```
':type a, ClassA, b, ClassB'
```

Any suggestions? Or is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed it works with this format:

```
class MyClass:

    def method(self, a, b):
        #: :type a: ClassA
        #: :type b: ClassB
```

It's also a bit more readable if you ask me. I've only been doing Python as a hobby for about a week, so don't take my word for it.

Nice thing about this format is that it works in for pretty much all type hinting (examples from PyDev manual):

```
class MyClass:

    def method(self, lst):
        #Can be on the same line
        for a in lst: #: :type a: GUITest
            a.;
```

or

```
class MyClass:

    def method(self, lst):
        #Or on the line before
        #: :type a: GUITest
        for a in lst:
            a.;
```